# Why am I getting problems in python string input? (Name not defined)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to create a football simulator and when I input a team name, it gives me a `name '' not defined error`. I'm coding on terminal with python 2.7:

```python
import time
import random
print("Welcome to The Football Simulator v1.0!")
team1 = input('Enter the first team ')
team2 = input('Enter the second team ')
venue = input('Where are they playing ')
print('Simulating...')
time.sleep(5)
def determineScore() :
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    if x <= 9:
            y = random.randint(1,6)
            if y <= 2:
                    score = 0
            elif y <= 4:
                    score = 1
            elif y == 5:
                    score = 2
            elif y == 6:
                    score = 3
    elif x == 10:
            score = random.randint(1,5)
    return score
team1Score = determineScore()
team2Score = determineScore()

print("==============RESULT==============")
print(team1, '                         ',team1Score)
print(team2, '                         ',team2Score)
```

Now I'll show you the error:

```
Welcome to The Football Simulator v1.0!
Enter the first team: barcelona
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "footballsimulator.py", line 4, in <module>
    team1 = input("Enter the first team: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'barcelona' is not defined.
```

Also, if I give it a name with space it says `unexpected EOF`.
Strangely, it works with numbers.

If I've made an eggheaded mistake, forgive me because I just started python and I'm only 13.

Answer (score 0):

`input` evaluates the input, and whatever string you put in threw the error. Use `raw_input` instead.